# PHP Gateway Time-out error handling

Tags: php, timeout, gateway

I am writing error free script and other script causing error, (both are same except 1 thing)

```
function test_function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    echo "<p>$errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline</p>";
    die;
}
set_time_limit(0);
set_error_handler ( 'test_function', E_ALL );
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
    sleep(1);
    echo "$i";
}
//output is 012345678

Second script 
function test_function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    echo "<p>$errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline</p>";
}
set_time_limit(0);
set_error_handler ( 'test_function', E_ALL );
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    sleep(1);
    echo "$i";
}

/*output

Gateway Time-out

The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.
*/
```

Actually my real code having while loop and it's taking time. Whenever it's taking more than 10 seconds, i am getting error. So, i created simplified code to prove myself. I want that if this error occur all data is saved and separate code execute that completes it. So, I will create recursive function, if more than 10 seconds, handle it and call function again.

Comment: this is similar, http://devsforrest.com/116/boost-settings-on-media-temple-for-maximum-settings but if i don't have access to php.ini and not access to command line. only php cli access

Comment: It is solved now, I asked hosting company to solve this problem and to raise timeout, and they raised, apache timeout from 10 seconds to 120 seconds and my script is running under 120 seconds and problem solved.